# SSL handsake failed nginx server

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm running a node js application rest api service and wordpress on same nginx server. There is android application which call my node js service to get data from the server. Many times I'm getting ssl handsake failed or refused error on my android application. While surfing my server configuration file and log file I'm getting this in my logs

> SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140A1175:SSL routines:SSL_BYTES_TO_CIPHER_LIST:inappropriate fallback) while SSL handshaking, client:::::

My nginx.conf file :

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes 4;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;

    events {
    worker_connections 8096;
    multi_accept on;
    }

     worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

    http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 45;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # buffer optimizations
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    }

    server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/crtfile.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            #try_files $uri $uri/index.html;

    }

    location = /index.html {return 301 https://appyappy.com/;}

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Also when no of users are too large around 2k-5k I'm also getting time out and connection refused error in adroid application.

Comment: why the `server` block is outside of the `http`

Comment: If the server is overloaded and failing to accept connections correctly, that may cause some clients (especially broswers?) to 'fallback' to an insecure version or configuration of SSL/TLS when they shouldn't. First fix the server so it handles the load and then see if you still get fallback errors. Near-crossdupes https://security.stackexchange.com/q/160922 and https://serverfault.com/q/663290/ and related https://security.stackexchange.com/q/94848/